# difference between data and newdata arguments when predicting

Tags: r, predict

When predicting in R, using the `predict()` function, the argument for the data on which we want to predict is `newdata =` . My question is, when putting `data =` instead of `newdata =`  what happens ? Because it doesn't give an error, and the rmse obtained is not the same when using `newdata =`

Here is an example:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(18)
Boston_idx = sample(1:nrow(Boston), nrow(Boston) / 2) 
Boston_train = Boston[Boston_idx,]
Boston_test  = Boston[-Boston_idx,]

library(rpart)
Boston_tree<-rpart(medv~., data=Boston_train)
tree.pred <- predict(Boston_tree, data=Boston_test)
tree.pred2 <- predict(Boston_tree, newdata=Boston_test)

rmse = function(m, o){
  sqrt(mean((m - o)^2))
}

rmse(tree.pred,Boston_test$medv)
rmse(tree.pred2,Boston_test$medv)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` are the data used for fitting the model, `newdata` are data used for prediction. The help page of `?predict.rpart` says:

> `newdata`: data frame containing the values at which predictions are required. The predictors referred to in the right side of `formula(object)` must be present by name in `newdata`. If missing, the fitted values are returned.

Comment: Okay so the fitted values are returned. And here by chance in my example there is the same number of samples in the training and test sets. I would have prefered pedagogically if `predit()` returns an error if `newdata` is missing.

Comment: Another student just wrote `predict(Boston_tree, new_data = Boston_test)`. He want to know why his rmse is different from colleagues.